# jquery combing selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

to be short : i want to select all the 'checked' checkboxes in my page except one of them !
so i tried this :

```
$('input:checkbox').not('#SpecificChbx').is(':checked')
```

i've tried this too :

```
$('input:checkbox:not(#SpecificChbx)').is(':checked')
```

i've tried so many alternatives but still not working .. any help please ?
this is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Dwe/) example

Comment: How is it "not working"? Can you make a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Why does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error?  Is there something off?  What happens and what do you expect?

Comment: @Mooseman Both are valid. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) returns true or false (if one of the matches checkboxes is checked it will return true, else false), what you want is a jQuery collection: `$('input:checkbox:checked:not(#SpecificChbx)')`

Comment: thank you sir .. it's short and simple and exactly what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over them...

```
$('input:checkbox').not('#SpecificChbx').filter(function () {
    return $(this).is(':checked');
}).each(function () {
    // Whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: this is working quite good, correct and worked for me! but it's a long code and it will make some extra load on the page
this is much simple and worked for me  
`$('input:checkbox:checked:not(#SpecificChbx)')`  

but than you after all